# Unable to Re-enable the Submit Button , When Form is having all Values using React

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I have all Form values and I am unable to Re-enable the submit button, What Mistake I am doing here? Can Anyone Please tell me how can I Re-enable the submit button..

Here is the Code, For Validating the Form,I have all Form values and I am unable to Re-enable the submit button, What Mistake I am doing here? Can Anyone Please tell me how can I Re-enable the submit button..

```
const [data, setdata] = useState({
        "UserName": "",
        "PhoneNumber": "",
        "email": "",
        "dropDown": "",
        "gender": [],
        "checking": [],
        // "id" :""
    })

    const [isInvalid, setisInvalid] = useState(true)

   const [checkBoxes, setcheckBoxes] = useState([
    {name:"HTML",isChecked:false},
    {name:"CSS",isChecked:false},
    {name:"Javascript",isChecked:false},
    {name:"ReactJS",isChecked:false}])

    const [radio, setradio] = useState([
        {name:"Male",isChecked:false},
        {name:"Female",isChecked:false}
    ])


    useEffect(()=>{
        validate()
      },[data])

    let dispatch = useDispatch();
    //Reading the Data from Store
    let readdatafromstore = useSelector((state) => {
        return state.keepdatatostore;
    })


    const handleChnage = (e) => {
            validate();
            setdata({ ...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

   const handleCheckChnage =(e) =>{
            // //console.log(e.target.value);
            // let value =e.target.value;
            //   console.log(value);
            //   let newchecks = {...data}
            //   //newchecks.checking.push(value);
            //   if(newchecks.checking.indexOf(value) === -1){
            //     newchecks.checking.push(value);
            //   }else {
            //       newchecks.checking.splice(newchecks.checking.indexOf(value) , 1);
            //   }
            //   setdata(data);
            var allCheckBoxes = [...checkBoxes]
            allCheckBoxes.forEach(cbox=>{
                if(cbox.name == e.target.value){
                  if(!cbox.isChecked){
                    cbox.isChecked=true
                  }else{
                    cbox.isChecked=false
                  }
        
                }
              
            })
        
            setcheckBoxes(allCheckBoxes)
           console.log(allCheckBoxes)
           validate();
   }

   const handleGenderChange =(e) =>{
       let newRadio =[...radio]
        //console.log(e.target.value);
        radio.forEach((rf)=>{
               rf.isChecked =false;
               if(rf.name === e.target.value){
                   rf.isChecked = true;
               }
        });
        setradio(newRadio);
        //console.log(newRadio);
        validate();
   }

   const validate = () =>{
    let valid = true
    let newUser = {...data}

    for(let a in newUser){
      if(a !== "checking"){
        if(newUser[a]===""){
          valid=false
        }
      }else if(a === "checking"){
        if(newUser[a].length === 0){
          valid=false
        }
      }
    }
    if(valid){
      setisInvalid(false)
    }else{
      setisInvalid(true)
    }

  }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let newData = {...data};
                  checkBoxes.forEach((e)=>{
                      //console.log(e)
                           if(e.isChecked){
                               newData.checking.push(e.name)
                           }
                  });
                     radio.forEach((rs)=>{
                          if(rs.isChecked){
                               newData.gender.push(rs.name);
                               // newData.gender = rs.name;
                          }
                     })
                     setdata(newData);
                     console.log(data);  
        dispatch(allActions.createData(data));
        
    }
```

Here I am doing the UI part I have all Form values and I am unable to Re-enable the submit button, What Mistake I am doing here? Can Anyone Please tell me how can I Re-enable the submit button..

```
<React.Fragment>
            <div className="container">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={adduser}>Add User</button>
            </div>
            {model && (
                <div className="modal" style={{ display: "block" }}>
                    <div className="modal-dialog" style={{ maxWidth: "60%" }}>
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-header">
                                <h5 className="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                                <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onClick={closeModal}></button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col">
                                            <div className="mb-3" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
                                                <label className="form-label fw-bold">UserName</label>
                                                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder='UserName' name="UserName" value={data.UserName} onChange={handleChnage} />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="mb-3" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
                                                <label className="form-label fw-bold">PhoneNumber</label>
                                                <input name="phone" className="form-control" placeholder='PhoneNumber' name="PhoneNumber" value={data.PhoneNumber} onChange={handleChnage} />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="mb-3" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
                                                <label className="form-label fw-bold">Email</label>
                                                <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder='EmailAddress' id="exampleInputEmail1" value={data.email} aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="email" onChange={handleChnage} />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col">
                                            <div className="mb-3" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
                                                <label className="fw-bold">DropDown Value</label>
                                                <select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="dropDown" value={data.dropDown} onChange={handleChnage} >
                                                    <option value="">Select From Dropdown</option>
                                                    <option value="ReactJS">ReactJS</option>
                                                    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
                                                    <option value="HtmlCss">HtmlCss</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="mb-3">
                                                <label className="mb-2 fw-bold">Gender</label>
                                                {
                                                    radio.map((rd)=>(
                                                        <div className="form-check">
                                                        <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" value={rd.name} checked={rd.isChecked} onChange={handleGenderChange} />
                                                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexRadioDefault1" >{rd.name}</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    ))
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="mb-3">
                                                <label className="mb-2 fw-bold">Checkbox Value</label>
                                                {
                                                    checkBoxes.map((cb)=><div className="form-check">
                                                    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checking" value={cb.name} checked={cb.isChecked} onChange={(e)=>{handleCheckChnage(e)}} />
                                                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexCheckDefault">{cb.name}</label>
                                                </div>
                                                )
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onClick={closeModal}>Close</button>
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={closeModal} disabled={isInvalid} onClick={handleSubmit}>Add User</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: `handleChnage` is strange: you `validate`, then `setdata` that will re-trigger a  `validate` with `useEffect`... Maybe a small refactoring could solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, did some refactoring and Now it is working

Comment: Very well. A periodical refactoring is always a good coice. Have a nice coding =)